# default TabBar application

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, xcode4, interface-builder, storyboard

Using XCode 4, I created a NEW TabBar Application using the default storyboard settings.

In my FirstViewController, I created a method called

```
- (IBAction)testMethod:(id)sender
```

In the UI (Interface Builder), I CTRL and dragged from the button to the FirstViewController and connected it to the method )testMethod.

However the methods never fire when the button is tapped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you connected your Button with Method in File Owner...  This is the normal mistake that everyone does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, however, I will take a guess and see if this helps...

If you run the App, the tab controller will switch between views when you tap the First and Second buttons on the tab bar.  I am guessing that you want to know when the First button is tapped and you are trying to get the button to fire off a different message (testMethod).  If this is correct, you may want to become a UITabBarDelegate rather than hooking the button.  This will allow you to control how the TabBar switches views.  You can prevent or allow the switch in tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: and react to the switch in tabBarController:didSelectViewController:.

If this is not what you are trying to do, please elaborate on what you mean by "the button" in  "dragged from the button" and perhaps even some insight into what the intention of testMethod is would help.

Comment: I dragged a UIButton from the library (in IB) to the FirstView. I tap the UIBUtton and nothing happens. I added a breakpoint in the code so when it triggers the button, I'd know. The breakpoint never executes.

Comment: I am having a difficult time reproducing this.  Here is what I did.  Create app, open FirstView.xib, Drag a Rounded Rect Button onto the view, CTRL Click to open FirstViewController.h as well as the .xib.  CTRL drag the button to the .h file so that it says "Insert Outlet, Action, or Outlet Collection".  When the dialog comes up, change the top selector to Action and the name to testMethod.  Break in testMethod.  All works OK.  Can you see a difference?

Comment: can I upload my project somewhere for you to access?

Comment: I do apologize, but I can't think of any good way to have you upload your project.  Could you make a project on codeplex or google code and let me know where it is?  I could get it from some place like that.